# Ansible 2.7 Multi Line ansible_managed

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Python3

Ansible 2.7

Does anybody have an example of a multi-line `ansible_managed` line in their ansible.cfg ?

In the olden days of ansible I was able to do ...

`ansible_managed = "#############################
 Dev Team Back Again
 By: {uid} on {host}
 Using template: {file}
 #############################"`

Now it must have been fixed, because it cuts off after the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get you most of the way there (all the way if you're not tied to the `#`'s):

```
ansible_managed =
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      Dev Team Back Again
       By: {uid} on {host}
        Using template: {file}
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

will give you the output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Dev Team Back Again
By: redacted_user on redacted_host
Using template: b'/Users/redacted_user/./template.yml'
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The `#` character needs to be quoted.

> In addition to ' and " there are a number of characters that are special (or reserved) and cannot be used as the first character of an unquoted scalar: [] {} > | * & ! % # ` @ ,.

In your example that would have worked fine but with whatever changes were made it is not possible.  You can put quotes around each line containing `#`'s but it adds them to the output.

For example:

```
"###########################"
Dev Team Back Again
By: redacted_user on redacted_host
Using template: b'/Users/redacted_user/./template.yml'
"###########################"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html